# Image filling in polygon using Raphael js or any another js

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

[image]

I am facing the issue on filling the background image within the polygon selected at roof top. 
I have successfully created the polygon, now I want that as soon as the image is selected from the number of slides present, that image should get filled within the selected polygon.
I am using Raphael js for doing the same, if possible with any other js then please advise.

Below is the code for testing purpose:

```
// Creates canvas 320 × 200 at 10, 50
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
//draw triangle
var t = paper.path("M0 0L250 0L100 100L 0");
// Sets the fill attribute of the circle to red (#f00)
t.attr("fill", "url('http://interlock.renoworks.com/en/data/exterior/Slate/~Interlock-01-SlateRoofing/~swatch1-400.jpg')");
// Sets the stroke attribute of the circle to white
t.attr("stroke", "#f00");
```

Here is the demo url: http://jsfiddle.net/hxez863d/5/

Comment: I would include some testing code.

Comment: @Ian I have added the testing code.

Comment: That seems to work fine for me (ie its filled with the image?) can you clarify what you want to happen that isn't in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You can clip a path in HTML5 without a library. Draw on the canvas after to put things in the clip region.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('can');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

var noise = makeNoise(300,200);
var squares = makeSquares(300, 200, 10, "#CCCCCC", "#999999");

// Draw background image.
ctx.drawImage(noise, 0, 0);


ctx.save();
//var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
ctx.translate(10, 50);

ctx.save();
//draw triangle
//var t = paper.path("M0 0L250 0L100 100L 0");
clipPath(ctx, [
  [0,0],
  [250, 0],
  [100, 100],
  [0, 0]
]);

// Draw with clip.
ctx.drawImage(squares, 0, 0);
ctx.fillRect(90, 70, 30, 30);
ctx.restore(); // <-- removes clip

// Draw without clip.
ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(100, 80, 30, 30);

ctx.restore(); // <-- removes translate

function clipPath(ctx, coords) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(coords[0][0], coords[0][1]);
  for (var i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]);
  }
  ctx.clip();
}

function makeNoise(w, h) {
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  can.width = w;
  can.height = h;
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h);
  var d = imageData.data;
  var len = d.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i+=4) {
    d[i] = d[i+1] = d[i+2] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    d[i+3] = 255;
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  return can;
}

function makeSquares(w, h, size, color1, color2) {
  var can = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  can.width = w;
  can.height = h;
  
  for (var y = 0; y < h; y+= size) {
    for (var x = 0; x < w; x += size*2) {
      ctx.fillStyle = color1;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
      ctx.fillStyle = color2;
      ctx.fillRect(x + size, y, size, size);
    }
    var temp = color1;
    color1 = color2;
    color2 = temp;
  }
  return can;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```